# How to import CSV excel file to R so that the output looks like excel table?

Tags: r, excel, import, copy

I would like to import data to R from an excel spreadsheet so that the data is presented in the same format as it is in Excel.

For example, I would like the data to be imported so that it looks like the following screenshot:

[image]

I have tried to upload the data by converting it to a csv file and entering the following code:

```
data5<- read.csv(file.choose(), header=T)
```

However, the data appears in R as follows:

[image]

This is not what I am looking for. Can you please advise me how to import it so that it looks like the excel table screenshot (image 1)?

Here is the link for the file:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mxjzSXon4NuQRFL5BhC4ngX5DgUdgJos?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Comment: Without having your data it would be hard to give any specific advice. However, you can try using readxl::read_excel() to import your data.

Comment: Thank you - here is the link: 

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mxjzSXon4NuQRFL5BhC4ngX5DgUdgJos?usp=sharing

Comment: You are actually successfully importing your data. However, when you go to view it the columns are wrapping due to the overall width of the data frame being pretty wide. dim(data5) of the example data you posted shows that you have 10 rows and 29 columns. If you drop the empty rows dim shows 4 rows and 29 columns. This would be your 3 data rows plus that extra row just below your header.

Comment: You can use `View(data5)` to get a spreadsheet-like view of the data

Comment: @rpolicastro, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @natej - thank you for that tip - that makes it easier to see things!